# Creating & using ContentProvider for android

Tags: android, couchdb, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, couchone

When I call an Android ContentProvider I get the following exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   start activity
>   ComponentInfo{de.harm.android.couchone/de.harm.android.couchone.CouchContactClient}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Unknown URL
>   content://de.harm.android.couchone.provider/test2

These are the projects:

- https://github.com/der-harm/CouchOneProvider
- .../CouchOneContacts

Android uses the so-called `ContentResolver` to communicate with `ContentProvider` which in turn handles the persistence functionality - accessing the database.

The `ContentProvider` registers itself with a unique Uri. The `ContentResolver` calls the `ContentProvider` with this Uri and passes additional data, like a SQL query string and/or data to be saved.

In the `CouchOneProvider`/`AndroidManifest.xml` I have the following:

```
<provider android:authorities="de.harm.android.couchone.provider"
   android:name=".Provider" />
```

The Provider uses

```
static {
    uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, DB_Name, URI_COLLECTION);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, DB_Name + "/#", URI_ENTITY);
}
```

and

```
public static boolean isCollectionUri(Uri uri) {
    return uriMatcher.match(uri) == URI_COLLECTION;
}
```

to process the `CONTENT_URI` used by the `ContentResolver` to call the `ContentProvider`:

- Am I missing permissions in any of both `AndroidManifest.xml`?
- Am I defining the authority in `AndroidManifest.xml` wrongly?
- Is the `CONTENT_URI` wrong?

**Update:**

I have additional information:

Logcat says:

> Failed to find provider info for
>   de.harm.android.couchone.provider

This should be the starting point. But so far I couldn't find any solution.

The fully qualified classname of the `ContentProvider` implementation is:

```
de.harm.android.couchone.Provider
```

In `AndroidManifext.xml` exactly this is specified as authority, except for the name being to lower case, but this should be fine.

The package name is defined previously in the xml file, so ".Provider" should be ok, too.

As to be seen in the exception, the client calls:

```
content://de.harm.android.couchone.provider/test2
```

Logcats answer is:

> Failed to find provider info for de.harm.android.couchone.provider

I don't see what's missing, perhaps it's Eclipse or emulator problem?

I install the provider as "run project as Android application".

Answer (score 3):

I have resolved this problem:

Both projects had the same package structure. I changed `de.harm.android.couchone` to `de.harm.android.couchone.provider` and `de.harm.android.couchone.client`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link is related to question topic. How to implement [a custom content-provider](http://web.archive.org/web/20120712055141/sohailaziz.com/2012/05/complete-contentprovider.html).